# namespace System.Web.Helpers using directive is unnecessary

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I have a project with System.Web.Helpers as a reference for the solution.  In one of my files I have

```
using System.Web.Helpers;
```

It tells me Using directive is unnecessary.  `AntiForgeryConfig` is within one of my files and it tells me 'The name 'AntiForgeryConfig' does not exist in the current context'.

```
var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Share your `AntiForgeryConfig` line of code. It is a static class. You cannot use the keyword `new` in front of it.

Comment: var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

Comment: Is this in your Controller, View? Is System.Web.Helpers in your References list? Did you remove `using System.Web.Helpers;` because it told you it was unnecessary? Have you tried using the full name instead like `var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];`? Maybe try posting some more code.